# Can't add table to Room database - Exception in log says 'expected' table is different from 'found'

Tags: java, database, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to add a second table to my Room database but it gives the following exception when I run the app.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle people_table(com.example.soundguard.People).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='people_table', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, priority=Column{name='priority', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='people_table', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

I have created a class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "people_table")
public class People {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String mName;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "priority")
    private int mPriority;

    public People(@NonNull String name, @NonNull int priority) {
        this.mName = name;
        this.mPriority = priority;
    }

    public String getName(){return this.mName;}
    public int getPriority(){return this.mPriority;}
    public void setPriority(int priority){this.mPriority = priority;}
}
```

And added the second entity as well as a migration in the database class, and so I am not sure why the found table is not matching the expected table:

```
@Database(entities = {AppName.class, People.class}, version = 4, exportSchema = true)
public abstract class SoundguardRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

...

static final Migration MIGRATION_3_4 = new Migration(3, 4) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`name` TEXT NOT NULL, `priority` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`name`))");
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you can use `${your_variable}` in java it's Kotlin code. As such the table that you have created would be created using :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`name` TEXT NOT NULL, `priority` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`name`))
```

i.e. the table name would be **${TABLE_NAME}** not **people_table** and hence why it found nothing.

So try using :-

```
@Database(entities = {AppName.class, People.class}, version = 4, exportSchema = true)
public abstract class SoundguardRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    ...

    static final Migration MIGRATION_3_4 = new Migration(3, 4) {
            @Override
            public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + TABLE_NAME + "` (`name` TEXT NOT NULL, `priority` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`name`))");
            }
        };
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. The problem was I copied the SQL phrase straight from the exported schema and just assumed it would work with Java code.